# Using regex to select players from list based on end of line character

Tags: python, regex

I'm trying to pick out the midfielders(M) from this list of players below using regex.
I've created a pattern to check for:

```
mids=re.findall('[\w\s\w:]*(?=\sM\n)',players)
```

however I'm not getting the desired result. I'd appreciate some help on where I've gone wrong.

```
Lionel Messi: F 
Cristiano Ronaldo: F 
NGolo Kante: M 
Ruben Dias: D    
Toni Kroos: M 
Sergio Ramos: D 
Paul Pogba: M 
Marcus Rashford: F 
Harry Kane: F 
Manuel Neuer G 
David DeGea: G
```

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use

```py
^.*?(?=: *M\s*$)
```

See [regex proof](https://regex101.com/r/zidAVB/1).

**EXPLANATION**

```py
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  ^                        the beginning of the string
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  .*?                      any character except \n (0 or more times
                           (matching the least amount possible))
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  (?=                      look ahead to see if there is:
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    :                        ':'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
     *                       ' ' (0 or more times (matching the most
                             amount possible))
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    M                        'M'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    \s*                      whitespace (\n, \r, \t, \f, and " ") (0
                             or more times (matching the most amount
                             possible))
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    $                        before an optional \n, and the end of
                             the string
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  )                        end of look-ahead
```

**[Pyton code](https://tio.run/##NY8xb4NADIV3foWFOgCKsnRDijKUlkYBFKXphho5wQkngY18R6X8enqU1pufP/v5DQ/XCj9Pk@kHUQdKwQAb0PBrnWyj7SaFpKxt8hSHgSPrztapH4eFEaYOSrLWpPAGNb@osc4gCxyFsWtkkatcOoE9sqMUSi8cxwsxZAZtChn4qvkkbGCvInZBPkjvxt/BXn6hmg84dnCQ@wUXokS9jtYTtr2JNovVO6o@Zita@hJ59D9WNJJC7oUMv00DGeXkz@Rh0KO7tmTnuLS@GW6w66JhBf9BV7NefhanXbGrXuNgUMMu@tuKp@kH)**:

```py
import re
p = r"^.*?(?=: *M\s*$)"
test_str = "Lionel Messi: F \nCristiano Ronaldo: F \nNGolo Kante: M \nRuben Dias: D    \nToni Kroos: M \nSergio Ramos: D \nPaul Pogba: M \nMarcus Rashford: F \nHarry Kane: F \nManuel Neuer G \nDavid DeGea: G"
matches = re.findall(p, test_str, re.MULTILINE)
print(matches)
```

**Results**: `['NGolo Kante', 'Toni Kroos', 'Paul Pogba']`

Comment: Hi @Ryszard, May I know the `*` in between the `:` and `M`, is to matching the most amount possible for the `:` or `M`?

Comment: @balandongiv It is matching zero or more spaces.

Comment: IIUC, your suggestion is to match a pattern of `:` , `space` and `m`? , and if match, extract the preceding string ? Thanks,